# What is this logic gate / electric symbol

Tags: integrated-circuit, serial, datasheet

I was looking through the MAX3232 datasheet (for a uni project) and I found these strange looking not gates (seen in the below picture) with an s-like symbol inside. I've been trying to find what it means (there are a couple of instances in the datasheet with no explanation as to what it is) and haven't been able to find examples by googling. It probably isn't a logic gate (seeing in what context it's brought up).

I'd be grateful to know what it is so I could read the circuit and know how it does what it's supposed to do.

[image: MAX3232 Operating Circuit and capacitor values]

[image: Test circuit with their waveforms]

Comment: The zig-zag parallelogram inside a Schmitt trigger represents hysteresis, i.e., it transitions at a different point going up going down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They represent ["Schmitt Triggers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger), gates whose inputs exhibit a hysteresis behaviour.

Essentially the threshold for detecting the input going from low to high is a lower voltage than the high to low threshold voltage. This means that there is much stronger noise rejection capability than a regular gate input. The hysteresis also helps avoid the output toggling on slowly rising/falling signal edges.